# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker app can't be reached on https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to get my app to run on https. It is a single instance, single container docker app, that runs dart code and serves on 8080. So far, the app runs on http perfectly. I do not have, nor want, a load balancer.
I have followed the directions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-docker.html and here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html. I also have it configured to connect to my site at "server.mysite.com". I am getting the refused to connect error. I am sort of a noob to this, so if you need more information let me know.

Comment: are you able to access the https endpoint locally in the container? Did you try to login to docker container using docker exec and curl to the https endpoint using localhost?

Comment: I am unsure. Allow me a little time to familiarize myself with that approach.

Comment: Please take your time. I am a little curious about what you mentioned about not using a load balancer. As I understand you have a single docker instance, hence using ALB is not needed. How are you planning to use your docker instance and use it externally?

Comment: The setup: a user access a certain domain host of my website (eg. aws.example.com) and is served an app. Honestly, I am newish to this, so unfamiliar with terms and such. So far, if they go to http://, they are served the app, but when https://', they get connection refused.

Comment: I would suggest you check for the following 1. As I have mentioned earlier please make sure that the application is accessible over HTTPS in the container itself.  you can go through the below links which can help https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/.  2. Check your security group, if you have granted access to the https port which is by default 443.

Comment: So, I think what is happening is the service is not registering. When I netstat -plant in the ec2 instance, it does not show 0.0.0.0:443 listener, even though I have followed the instructions as I mentioned in my post. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Im sorry, I have no idea about dart code, but which server is running in your instance? Is it nginx ? The first link talks about configuring nginx with ssl, is that what you have configured? Is the nginx running successfully on port 8080 now ?

Comment: I figured it out. It was an AWS thing. Updating the answer now with what worked. I thank you for your assistance in this matter. I truly wish you the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the instance is not listening on 443. So it turns out that since I deployed on AWS Linux 2, there is a different way of configuring the location of the https.conf file that the docs make you make.
Here is a ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html. Essentially, I made a folder in the root (next to .ebextensions) and added a file with the following path .platform/nginx/conf.d/https.conf with the contents of the file the wanted in the docs, eg.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000;
      proxy_http_version  1.1;
      proxy_set_header  Connection "";
      proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```